# Eigenvalues and operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-norm

> $A: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is $2 \times 2$ matrix with eigenvalues $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{9}{5}$. Prove that there exists
>
> 1. a non-zero vector $v$ with $\|Av\|> 2\|v\|$, and
> 2. a non-zero vector $v$ with $\|Av\|<\frac{1}{2} \|v\|$.

---

By defining a continuous function from the unit circle $S$ in the plane, (which is a compact set) to the real line, I conclude that the image contains the closed interval $[\frac{2}{3}, \frac{9}{5}]$. But how do I conclude that the image doesn’t contain $\frac{1}{2}$ and $2$? Help solicited.

Comment: For (1), did you mean $>\color{red}2\| v\|?$

Comment: Since ${9 \over 5}$ is an eigenvalue there **must** be some $v\neq 0$ such that $\|Av\| = {9 \over 5} \|v\|$.

Comment: And if that is all the information given, then for any $M>0$ one can find an $A$ with those eigenvalues such that $\|Av\| > M\|v\|$.

Comment: Neither of the above statements is true with the given conditions. Are you sure you have given all the information??? Is $A$ symmetric perhaps?

Comment: Where did this question come from?

Comment: This question is from an entrance examination for Ph D in Mathematics by a reputed institution called the Chennai Mathematical Institute, India. Year 2013. Nothing is said about A except that it’s a linear transformation from R^2 to R^2 with eigen values 2/3 and 9/5. Then there exists a non zero vector v in R^2 such that (a) ||Av||>2||v|| (b) ||Av||<1/2 ||v|| (c) ||Av||=||v|| (d) Av=0. The answer given is option (c) is true and the other 3 options are false.

Comment: @copper.hat I have answered your questions.

Comment: @LawrenceMano: My answer gives an example that shows that (a), (b) are false. So there is no inconsistency.

Comment: @copper.hat Your examples show that (a) and (b) are true. So the question is wrong.

Comment: I have shown that (1), (2) in the question above are false.

Comment: @copper.hat You are right. But the original question is the negation of the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $A=\begin{bmatrix} {2 \over 3} & 1000 \\ 0 & {9 \over 5}\end{bmatrix}$.

Note that $\|A (0,1)^T\| > 1000$.

Let $v=(\sqrt{1-{1 \over 1000^2}}, -{1 \over 1000^2})^T$, then and note that
$Av = ({2\over 3} \sqrt{1-{1 \over 1000^2}}-1, {9 \over 5000})^T$
and $\|Av\| \le \sqrt{{1\over 3^2} + {1 \over 10^2}} < {11 \over 30} < { 1\over 2}$.

Comment: +1! Constructing such counterexamples must be due to some divine power. Great as always.

Comment: @NitinUniyal: :-). Not divine, unfortunately, just Octave for quick experiments.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for the inspiring examples.